# How do I change the href of a link on click, then go to the updated link?

Tags: jquery

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Click `<a/>`
2. Run function that updates the `href` of `<a/>`
3. Pretend like nothing happened and allow the click through utilizing the updated href

The approach I'm trying ends up creating an endless click loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mousedown` event (instead of the `click` event).

Here is an example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').mousedown(function(e) {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).data('link'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.google.com" data-link="http://www.stackoverflow.com">www.google.com</a>
```